# Saving a Range in a variable in VBA to use with multiple files

Tags: excel, vba

In this project, I need to copy information from multiple files and paste them into the master file. The user will first select the .CSV files they wish to open. Next they will select the range of data they wish to copy from each file. Then the program will take that information from each file and put it in the master file.

I am unable to get this range object to work for me. I cannot select variable range with anything. I have tried using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(rng).Copy
```

```
filenames(i).ActiveSheet.Range(rng).Copy
```

I have tried using rng.address but that doesn't seem to work for me either.

And may other different ways but nothing works. I assume that I am doing something wrong with the range variable, but I don't know what is wrong. I have tried placing the code before I close the original workbook too but that also hasn't worked.

I have been getting run-time error :'9' or run-time error'424'.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub importData()

Dim awb As Workbook, twb As Workbook
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim filenames() As Variant, content() As Variant
Dim nc As Integer, nw As Integer, nr As Integer
Dim rng As Range, r As Range
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set twb = ThisWorkbook

'Has the user select workbooks to open
filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel filter (*.csv), *csv", Title:="Open File(s):", MultiSelect:=True)
nw = UBound(filenames)

'Has the user select the range that wish to copy into the master file
Workbooks.Open filenames(1)
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range: ", Title:="Range Input", Type:=8)
nr = rng.Rows.Count
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

ReDim content(nw, nr)

'Opens all the workbooks and copys the selected area
For i = 1 To nw
    Workbooks.Open filenames(i)
    Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
    j = 1
    
    'This following line is causing my all the problems
    filenames(i).ActiveSheet.Range(rng).Copy

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set awb = Workbooks.Open(filenames(i))`, then `awb.Worksheets(1).Range(rng.Address).Copy`.

Comment: I have done that; however, I still get the run-time error'424' object required error.

Comment: Try `Dim add As String`, `add = rng.Address` after `Set rng = Application.InputBox...`, then use `awb.Worksheets(1).Range(add).Copy`

Comment: That works. Thanks for the help! Do you know why I had to do that to make this work? I am new to VBA, so if you know anywhere to learn more, I would appreciate. the help.

Comment: The problem is that `rng` becomes `Nothing` when you close the original workbook. You need to store its `Address` as a `String` while the original workbook is still open.

Answer (score 0):

### Import Range from Several CSV Files

- The following will (after the user input) copy the same range from each source workbook  (worksheet (`CSV` meaning one worksheet per workbook)) to the given (destination) worksheet (dName) of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), one below the other.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub importData()
    
    ' Constants
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dwb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
    
    ' Source
    
    'Have the user select the workbooks to open
    Dim FileNames As Variant: FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel filter (*.csv),*csv", Title:="Open File(s):", _
        MultiSelect:=True)
    
    'Validate file names
    If VarType(FileNames) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation, "File Selection"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fCount As Long: fCount = UBound(FileNames)
    
    'Have the user select the range that is to be copied into the master file
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Workbooks.Open(FileNames(1)).Worksheets(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Select range: ", Title:="Range Input", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Validate range
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sws.Parent.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbCritical, "Range Selection"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rAddress As String: rAddress = rng.Address
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rng.Rows.Count
    
    ' Copy
    
    'Open all the workbooks and copy the selected range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To fCount
        Set sws = Workbooks.Open(FileNames(n)).Worksheets(1)
        sws.Range(rAddress).Copy dCell
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sws.Parent.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(rCount)
    Next n

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Inform user
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```